# position absolute/relative for class and its tags

Tags: html, css, tags

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ofJD.jpg)

I have a class with position relative and trying to set the position of its tag to absolute. As soon as i set the position to absolute, everything in my site would disappear.here is CSS

```
   .container {
    display: flex;
    width: 90vh;   */I didnt have this line in my code first
    }

     .panel {
        position:relative;
        }
        .panel h3{
        position:absoloute;
        bottom: 5px;
        left: 5px;
    
        }
```

Comment: with the absolute position you need to specify top, left and right.

Comment: @hussain it was included in original code, still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using the browser's devtools to see where the elements are? The issue might be different from what is presented.

Comment: @IamL they are there(position wise) but content isn't showing, when i check box the position absolute on dev tool css, they appear.

Comment: insert your html here pls

Comment: @sergeykuznetsovi its attached as pic

Comment: panel is wrapped in .container which is flex but i didnt define any width, for some reason that was an issue, but i dont understand why

Answer (score 0):

Parent(panel) could not have sensible height based on child elements that are all absolute positioned. In your case, height of panel will be 0 because there is no child elements that are positioned neither absolute or fixed.

Not sure why you are trying to position bottom: 5px, left: 5px.

If you just want 5px space from bottom, left then you can use padding.

```css
.panel {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Else if you want positioned layout, then parent(.panel) should have sensible height manually via css.

```css
 .panel {
    position:relative;
    height: 50px;
    /* if not set width manually, default is 100% */
 }
 .panel h3{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
 }
```

else if you want content height based on background image and position h3 tag, you should insert img tag instead of background.

```css
.panel {
      position: relative;
    }

    .panel img {
      /* if you will need to adjust width and height, you can enter here */
      /* width: 100%;*/
      /* height: 200px;*/
      /* object-fit: cover*/
    }

    .panel h3 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 5px;
      bottom: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel active">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSCfr.png"/>
    <h3>This is image 1</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it will be help for you.

Comment: thanks for demonstration. i have 5 dives with class name panel and each has an image and h3 in them. they are all children of a .container. i was trying to position each h3 to bottom left of each panel. I know now that my panel MUST have width or height set, since its relative...

Comment: Happy to hear :)